# Prevent Parallels from dismounting data HDD when starting Windows

Tags: windows-7, macos, parallels

I've got two harddrives in my Macbook. A SSD with OSX and Windows 7 (via Bootcamp) on it and a ordinary HDD for data which is formated as exFat (because both OSX and Windows can read/write it).

I'm able to boot into Windows natively and also inside OSX via Parallels. All is working like a charm but one thing.

In Bootcamp the data HDD is mounted with drive letter F. To see it when booting via Parallels as well I added a HDD to the virtual machine pointing to the data HDD.
When I start Parallels it gets drive-letter F like its supposed to.

However Parallels dismounts the data drive on OSX when starting Windows. I can still access it via another folder it has mounted called "[F] Boot Camp" in Finder but since the name is different programs on OSX who have data saved on the data-partition won't find them anymore.

Do you have any idea on what I can do about this?